# 3 way switches controlling 2 lights simultaneously

Tags: wiring

I have 2- 3 way switches. One at the top of the stairs near our outside door and one  at the bottom of the stairs. Both switches are controlling  lights at those locations simultaneously. I don't want the bottom switch to control the top light anymore. I want the top light to be controlled only by the switch at the top of the stairs. There is a  14/2  wire going from the top switch to the light fixture downstairs and then to the 3 way switch downstairs. There is also a 14/3 wire from the upstairs going to the 3 way downstairs. Problem is both switches are controlling both lights. I don't want the upstairs light controlled by the downstairs 3 way switch. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you upload pictures showing all the wires going to the switches and (if accessible) to the light fixtures?

Comment: This is rhetorical because I am sure you are aware of the practical reason for having both switches control the light at the top of the stairs...

Comment: You can't do that, that's a Code violation.  Lights covering stairways MUST be controllable from both the bottom and top of the stairway.  Or, be on motion sensor.

Comment: What problem is having the upstairs light on both switches causing for you?